# Which standard c++ functions and types support reentrancy?

Tags: c++, reentrancy

The C++ Standard (c++14 and also the [current working draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/reentrancy)) states that

> Except where explicitly specified in this document, it is
> implementation-defined which functions in the C++ standard library may
> be recursively reentered.

Except of [std::recursive_mutex](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.mutex.recursive) I couldn't find any type or function in the standard where it is explicitly specified that it can be recursively reentered safely. Even for std::recursive_mutex the standard states that:

> It is unspecified how many levels of ownership may be acquired by a
> single thread.

My questions for C++17:

1. Which types or functions, defined by the C++ standard, have to be implemented in a way that they can be recursively reentered?
2. Reentrant code may not call non-reentrant functions (see rules for reentrancy below). With this in mind, is it correct to summarize that C ++ code can only be safely reentrant if no C++ standard types or functions are used?

Please note, that [reentrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29) and thread-safety are orthogonal concepts:

> In computing, a computer program or subroutine is called reentrant if
> multiple invocations can safely run concurrently on a single processor
> system, where a reentrant procedure can be interrupted in the middle
> of its execution and then safely be called again ("re-entered") before
> its previous invocations complete execution. The interruption could be
> caused by an internal action such as a jump or call, or by an external
> action such as an interrupt or signal, unlike recursion, where new
> invocations can only be caused by internal call.

> This definition of reentrancy differs from that of thread-safety in
> multi-threaded environments. (...) Conversely, thread-safe code does
> not necessarily have to be reentrant (...)

[Rules for reentrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29):

> Reentrant code may not hold any static or global non-constant data.

> Reentrant code may not modify itself.

> Reentrant code may not call non-reentrant computer programs or routines.

Comment: "Reentrancy" is something completely different from "recursively reentered". You are conflating two completely different things.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What is your point? The section 16.4.6.9 of the C++ standard I referenced is "Reentrancy" and the text uses "recursively reentered". If you explain in detail why do you think that "reentrancy" is something completely different from "recursively reentered" I can try to improve my question.

Comment: Reentrancy, in the context of applications and libraries, refers to which library functions can be safely called from a ***signal handler***. The C++ standard may use that term, except that that signal handling is mostly outside of its scope and it's using this term very narrowly. But without clarification as to what ***exactly*** you're referring to, "reentrancy" generally means reentrancy from a signal handler. Recursively reentered has nothing to do with signal handlers, whatsoever.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the clarification. Why do you think that the C++ standard refers only to signal handling in §16.4.6.9? That is not explicitly mentioned in the standard. It is true that reentrancy is important for signal handlers and one of two two possible choices to implement a signal-safe function (see eerorika's answer). But reentrancy is e.g. also possible when a callback is provided by a library. See also [this open LWG issue](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2382) not related to signal handling. Summary: when only signal handling is in focus it would be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Which types or functions, defined by the C++ standard, have to be implemented in a way that they can be recursively reentered?

Reentrancy is a pre-requisite for asynchronous signal safety. Therefore functions which are specified as signal-safe must be implemented as reentrant.

> [support.signal]
>
> An evaluation is signal-safe unless it includes one of the following:
>
> - a call to any standard library function, **except for plain lock-free atomic operations** and functions explicitly identified as signal-safe;

> A plain lock-free atomic operation is an invocation of a function f from [atomics], such that:
>
> - f is the function atomic_­is_­lock_­free(), or
> - f is the member function is_­lock_­free(), or
> - f is a non-static member function invoked on an object A, such that A.is_­lock_­free() yields true, or
> - f is a non-member function, and for every pointer-to-atomic argument A passed to f, atomic_­is_­lock_­free(A) yields true.

As such, those plain lock-free atomic opreations must be reentrant.

Comment: Great you mention async-signal-safe. I am aware of the limitations for [signal handlers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) and the definition of [async-signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). However, async-signal-safe could be also achieved by blocking signal delivery and then the function must not necessarily be reentrant. Therefore, I am not 100% sure if all functions of e.g. std::atomic can be safely recursively reentered.

Comment: @Sonic78 Good point. Reentrancy might not be required for async safety after all.